# Safari browser unable to reapply ellipsis on object resize

Tags: css, safari, frontend

I have a container with an `<h3>` element with a nested `<a>`. All of this is part of a "product card", which is reused in many places. The style of the text:

```
h3 {

display: block;
margin: 0 1rem 1.1rem 1rem;

  a {
    color: #000;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    font-weight: 500;

    line-height: 1.7rem;
    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
  }
```

}

However, while it all works fine, Safari forgets to apply the ellipsis style some times, on some elements. Some of those times may be on page load, and others may be on resize. My boss has reported that this also happens on his iPhone.

Here is how it looks in the page:

[image: https://imgur.com/a/tzFanKs]

That is the same element, with the same style, on the same page, but one has 3 lines (there is an overlay over the bottom object, while the top one is inside a drawn header).

I can see this style getting lost while resizing Chrome, but it always gets reapplied properly when I stop. If I open developer tools and disable and reenable any of the styles, the ellipsis gets reset properly. This makes me think that I am fighting with a bug.

Originally the styles were outside of the anchor and I also tried with an `<h3>` element only - same result.

So, questions are: what is going on, and how to patch this?